# How to deploy android library on gradle or google repositry?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-gradle-plugin, shared-libraries

I've got few libraries which I want to deploy on Gradle(google repository, etc)
so that anybody can access it using Gradle as we do in android studio app.gradle file

**Eg :  implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'**

I want to know the process of deploying, I already have the libraries.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Make library module in Android Studio** [ Assumed that you have prepared ]

**2. Create Space on Bintray**

[image]

Fill in the required information as shown below with your exact module name and your GitHub repo links and click on “Create Package”.

Congrats! You have successfully completed the second step.

**3. Upload your library on Bintray and JCenter**

Now you need to configure your library so that you can upload it to Bintray followed by JCenter.
Modify the project build.gradle file by adding these below dependencies:

```
dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
   classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7'
   classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
}
```

Add your Bintray authentication details in the local.properties file. That information should not be pushed to the version control system.

bintray.user= “YOUR USERNAME”
bintray.apikey= “YOUR API KEY”

You can find both credentials in your account by following these steps-
Open your Bintray account, click on your name and then click edit under your name and then the API Key tab.
[image]

Now we need to modify our module build.gradle file. Open the file and modify according to the below-mentioned steps.

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
   }
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
   }
}

ext {
   bintrayRepo = 'Utility' // your repo name
   bintrayName = 'time-utils' // has to be same as your library module name
   publishedGroupId = 'com.timeutility' // your module package name
   libraryName = ‘time-utils’ 
   artifact = 'time-utils' // has to be same as your library module name
   libraryDescription = 'A set of methods used to manipulate time object'
   siteUrl = 'https://github.com/androidCode/time-utils'
   gitUrl = 'https://github.com/androidCode/time-utils.git'
   libraryVersion = '1.0'
   developerId = ‘sachit’
   developerName = Sachit
   developerEmail = 'sachit.wadhawan@quovantis.com'
   licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
   licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
   allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
}


android {
   // -------- your target version and all required configuration. These are normal as for other projects and generate by android studio itself
   }

dependencies {
   // Your dependecies
}
// add it to the bottom of the file

apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/numetriclabz/jcenter/master/installv.gradle'
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/numetriclabz/jcenter/master/bintrayv.gradle'
```

Sync the project. Once everything is configured, run the command below in your terminal, in root of the project.

```
./gradlew clean build install bintrayUpload
```

Shout Hurray! if it shows BUILD SUCCESSFUL.

Check your package in the Bintray web interface. You will see a change in Versions area. Now it needs to be pushed to JCenter. Now once your project is up on Bintray, simply hit “Add to JCenter” button to sync with JCenter.

It may take a few hours before your request has been accepted. When it happens, you should get a notification via email and also see the jCenter badge in your package details under the “Linked to” section.

Congratulations! Your library is now on jCenter!!! You can give the gradle path into your project now. For example my dependency looks like this:

```
implementation 'xxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxx:1.0'
```

Thank You :)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You need an artifactory. You can use public ones like [maven-central](https://mvnrepository.com/repos/central), [jitpack](https://jitpack.io/) or create your own by using [JFrog](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/).

Then update your library project that able to work with maven to create an artifact.
After that, you are ready to publish.

I would suggest to use jitpack if you are not familiar since its a huge topic.